# Как подсчитать длину всех лучей?

Tags: c#, unity3d

День добрый! У меня возникла проблема: не могу понять, как мне определить длину каждого луча? Когда луч (ray1) сталкивается с обьектом, то в переменную `hit` записывается результат столкновения, и можно получить длину (`hit.distance`). А вот как вывести длину по всем 4 лучам сразу? Догадываюсь, что нужно использовать массив и перебор,  но не могу написать код. Вот, что у меня пока есть:

```
public Transform[] thrusters = new Transform[4];
public float size_ray;
void  FixedUpdate (){
    RaycastHit hit;
    int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < thrusters.Length; i++) {
            Vector3 direction = thrusters[0].transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.down * size_ray);
            Vector3 direction1 = thrusters[1].transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.down * size_ray);
            Vector3 direction2 = thrusters[2].transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.down * size_ray);
            Vector3 direction3 = thrusters[3].transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.down * size_ray);

            Ray ray0 = new Ray(thrusters[0].position,Vector3.down);
            Ray ray1 = new Ray(thrusters[1].position,Vector3.down);
            Ray ray2 = new Ray(thrusters[2].position,Vector3.down);
            Ray ray3 = new Ray(thrusters[3].position,Vector3.down);

            Debug.DrawLine(thrusters[0].position,direction,Color.green);
            Debug.DrawLine(thrusters[1].position, direction1,Color.red);
            Debug.DrawLine(thrusters[2].position, direction2,Color.white);
            Debug.DrawLine(thrusters[3].position, direction3,Color.blue);

        if (Physics.Raycast (ray1,out hit,size_ray))
            {   
                if(hit.collider){
                    Debug.Log("name-"+hit.collider.name+"/distance-"+hit.distance);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как мне это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

```
var rays = new List<Ray>();
// заполнение лучей
rays.ForEach(ray =>
                    {
                        RaycastHit hit;
                        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, size_ray))
                        {
                            if (hit.collider)
                            {
                                Debug.Log("name-" + hit.collider.name + "/distance-" + hit.distance);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: что такое ForEach? В любом случае этот код не работает у меня

Comment: Чтобы работал форич необходимо добавить неймспейс с Линком. Не знаю насколько он доступен в вашем контексте, но етот код заменяется на банальный цикл (тело цикла без изменений).

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не работает?